# How to preview a non publishable item

Tags: publishing

I have a content item in the CMS, which is like an admin page for content authors. This item should never go to the web database, but authors should be able to use it by the preview mode.

When I set the `Lifetime` to an older date or `Never Publish` settings for this item, and try to preview it, it doesn't load. Instead it loads the factory default home page.

I'm planning to make this item as a reusable component, to be used in any other instance.

Is there any alternate way in which we can make it non publishable and yet preview it.

Comment: Can you change the Publishable From date to year 3000? And use Preview Date in the Experience Editor?

Comment: What site have you defined for previewing?

Comment: Try this http://website/en/?sc_mode=preview&sc_date=20180625, sc_date is publish date

Comment: You can create a command in ribbon and on the click of that button create url like this http://website/en/?sc_mode=preview&sc_date=20180625

Comment: @GauravAgarwal. What should the date be. Current / Past or Future?

Comment: @Qwerty please try never publish date and for publishable try future date

Comment: @GauravAgarwal. I'm planning to use this as a reusable component for other sites as well. So, looking for a simpler solution.

Answer (score 2):

You can create a subdomain for preview:

1.Create a (sub)domain for preview (e.g. preview.mysite.com) and setup DNS as needed

2.Add the preview host to the existing IIS Sitecore instance

3.Add a new  node to the Sitecore instance’s config files

4.Set the new site to listen to the master database

```
<site name="website_preview" filterItems="false" enableWorkflow="true" hostName="preview.mysite.com" virtualFolder="/" physicalFolder="/" rootPath="/sitecore/content" startItem="/home" database="master" domain="extranet" allowDebug="true" cacheHtml="true" htmlCacheSize="10MB" registryCacheSize="0" viewStateCacheSize="0" xslCacheSize="5MB" filteredItemsCacheSize="2MB" enablePreview="true" enableWebEdit="true" enableDebugger="true" disableClientData="false" />
```

More information you can find here: http://firebreaksice.com/how-to-setup-a-sitecore-preview-site-to-review-content-before-publishing/

Comment: Sorry I did not mention the other part which is making the item as a reusable component too be used in any other instance. For users,who wll use this package, setting up a DNS, host etc could be complex.

Comment: Never the less; the solution Vlad gives you here is the official solution to previewing items with publishing restrictions.

Comment: This does not work for items marked as "Not Publishable", it only works for Publishable items that have not been published to the web database. Subtle but important difference.

Comment: @jammykam did same, and only publishable item and previewed.